# Two alignments in math mode

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I've created a vector equation using the following:

```
$$x_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+
  x_2\begin{bmatrix}2\\-5\end{bmatrix}+
  x_3\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\end{bmatrix}
 =\begin{bmatrix}4\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
```

This creates a center-aligned vector equation.

I'd now like to add the words "vector equation" on the same line, aligned to the right. How can I do this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/134144 might be worth having a look at.

Comment: Don't use `$$ $$`. Instead of, use `equation` environment and then use `\tag{vector equation}` inside it to change the equation tag.

Comment: @leandriis Someone else pointed this out to me, but I haven't had a chance to read through the literature yet, so I'm still working with the old `$$` for now.